# Create object with new key and assign same array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Do you have an optimised solution for the following.

let say,

```
x = { users: [ {id: 1}, {id:2}, {id:3} ] }
```

I want to make a new key with same values, the output should be,

```
{ users: { list: [ {id: 1}, {id:2}, {id:3} ], count: 3 }
```

**Using only JS or Underscore with one line code w/o any extra effort.**

I know other tricks to do the same, but do we have one line solution for the same ?
Help appreciated...
Thanks.

Comment: your output is invalid. should count be a property of users, or of the enclosing (unnamed) object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is to be an *optimised solution* because this is a simple plain-JavaScript problem:

```js
let x = { users: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] };
let result = {
  users: {
    list: x.users,
    count: x.users.length
  }
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ok, I just find my mistake here, actually I'm trying obj.user.list = { obj.users }, so I'm having array with new object too..

Comment: huh @BHARGAV - this gives you exactly what you want in the question

Comment: @BHARGAV -- I didn't get you quite right here. Could you elaborate? Or my answer is your desired solution?

Answer (score 3):

Create the object, and assign the `x` array to `list`. However, `count` should be a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), since the `list` length might change:

```js
const x = { users: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] };
const result = {
  users: {
    list: x.users,
    get count() { return this.list.length; }
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

result.users.list.push({ id: 4 });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just define the property as an object

```js
const obj = {
  users: [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3
  }]
};
obj.users = { list: obj.users, count: obj.users.length };
console.log(obj);
```

I recommend focusing on code clarity rather than on line conservation though

Comment: Ok, I just find my mistake here, actually I'm trying obj.user.list = { obj.users }, so I'm having array with new object too..

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clear what you're *actually* trying to find?